# Need help finding eigenvectors of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following Matrix:

$$B= \begin{bmatrix}
8 & -6 & -6 \\
30 & -22 & -30 \\
-30 & 30 & 38 
\end{bmatrix}  $$

I find the characteristic polynomial as:

$$det(B-\lambda E)=-(\lambda-8)^3$$

So we have the root 8 (with multiplicty 3). Therefore $B$ has the eigenvalue 8

Now I solve for

$$(B-\lambda E)x= \begin{bmatrix}
8-8 & -6 & -6 \\
30 & -22-8 & -30 \\
-30 & 30 & 38-8 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\
y \\
z
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}  $$

$$0x-6y-6z=0$$
$$30x-30y-30z=0$$
$$-30x+30y+30z=0$$

I find the solutions to the equations as:

$$x=0$$
$$y=-1$$
$$z=1$$

Am I going in the right direction? What does the results tell me about which eigenvectors exist for the matrix B?

Comment: Well, this tells you it has exactly one eigenvector, of eigenvalue 8. This is correct. Unless the matrix is hermitian, the number of eigenvectors (ie. dimension of the eigenspace) for a specified eigenvalue can be less than its multiplicity.  You should look up on generalized eigenvectors (eigenvectors for $(B−λE)^k$ ). These are indeed equal in number to the multiplicity of the eigenvalue.  You should look up generalized eigenvectors and the Jordan normal form:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done so far is find an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda=8$. This doesn't tell you anything about other possible (linearly independent) eigenvectors. To determine their existence, you'll need to determine $\mathrm{dim}N(\lambda I - B)$, where $N(\cdot)$ denotes the null space. Looking at the linear system, we can see that we must have $x=0$. Then, we can easily see that, though there are infinitely many solutions, they are all of the form
$$v=\begin{pmatrix} 0\\ v_2\\ -v_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
Therefore, there is only the one linearly independent eigenvector (i.e., $\mathrm{dim}N(\lambda I - B) = 1$).